# How to not wrap Webpack plugin in parens

Tags: javascript, syntax, webpack

I have a simple Webpack plugin for converting Node-specific uses of `global` to `window` for the browser context.

```js
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      global: 'window'
    })
  ],
```

The swap is represented as `(window)` in the bundled code, which causes compilation errors in dependencies (which I don't control) without semicolons. For example:

```js
var x = foo(example)
global.bar()

// becomes

var x = foo(example)
(window).bar()

// which is equivalent to

var x = foo(example)(window).bar()
```

Which is junk. How can I stop Webpack from wrapping the value in parens?

Comment: I'm no webpack expert but have you tried putting semicolons after each instruction.

Comment: Clarified in the question, but the code that's breaking isn't mine, or even code I'm directly referencing. It's a dependency of a dependency and I can't change it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible because webpack doesn't offer any options and the parentheses are there for grouping. Because they can be expressions, the parentheses allow for the grouping and subsequent correct evaluation.

Comment: This seems like a pretty glaring issue though. Is there some way to inject semicolons before the substitution happens?